# Can I deduct costs associated with rental improvements?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, rental-property, depreciation, capital-improvements

I have a back ADU (accessory dwelling unit) at my home in Portland Oregon that I rent out. I live in the main house and the ADU is a totally separate 800 square foot house with a separate address but on the same property. It’s rented 100% of the year on a 12-month lease This fall I had a patio constructed - with landscaping and an added a hot tub, the cost was $50,000. The renters share the patio and hot tub with me. Can I deduct or depreciate any of the costs on my taxes?

Comment: You may be able to increase the rent due to the increased quality of the amenities. But that money would come from the renters and has nothing to do with taxes.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. There's a difference between an operating expense and a capital improvement. An capital improvement results in a long-term asset, while an operating expense is immediately consumed. If you pay to have the lawn mowed, the lawn will grow back in a few days, so that's an operating expense. If you pay to have sod put in, the lawn should last for several years, so that's a capital improvement.

Money spent on capital improvements can generally be added to the cost basis of the property, and so you can deduct them from the sale price when you sell. There's also various depreciation schedules for different capital improvements. Each year, the depreciation is subtracted from the cost basis, and is available to be claimed as a deduction.

A further complication is the fact that the improvement is available for your personal use. If the IRS accepts it as being 50% deductible, then every year you can claim half of that year's depreciation as an expense for the rental.